How to serve two laravel projects in nginx server?
I want to serve multiple Laravel apps in a single nginx server, the first one has a root directory in /var/www/html/project1, the second one has /var/www/html/admin, and so on.
Here is the code. Our domain name is example.com, and the admin panel will run on example.com/admin. The application is developed in Laravel. Could you please verify this code and confirm with us?
My current nginx conf file is as below:
server {
listen 80;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
listen 443 ssl;
server_name example.com www.example.com;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cgstaging_cert/cgstaging.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cgstaging.key;
root /var/www/projects/project1;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
# Subfolder Configuration for Admin Panel
location /admin {
alias /var/www/projects/admin;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/projects/project2/admin$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
}
# PHP handling for main domain
location ~ \.php$ {
include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;
}
# Deny access to hidden files except .well-known
location ~ /\.(?!well-known).* {
deny all;
}
# Custom error page for 404 errors
error_page 404 /index.php;
# Additional error logging
error_log /var/log/nginx/cgstaging_error.log;
}


But, nginx always returning 404 page result. What's going wrong here?
